# An unmarshaling policy check was performed when unmarshaling a custom marshaled object and the class {45FB4600-E6E8-4928-B25E-50476FF79425}

Tags: windows, azure, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I'm getting the following error message in Azure Windows 10 Application Event log periodically:

```
An unmarshaling policy check was performed when unmarshaling a custom marshaled object and the class {45FB4600-E6E8-4928-B25E-50476FF79425} was rejected
```

Windows version is 21H1 OS Build 19043.1387.

I saw the same report dated December 13, 2013, on an [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/325ab240-5eff-4a4b-9f5b-2eaf2a4002ed/an-unmarshaling-policy-check-was-performed-when-unmarshaling-a-custom-marshaled-object-and-the-class?forum=systemcenterservicemanager) but no solution since that.

Here is the XML view of the report.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-COMRuntime" Guid="{bf406804-6afa-46e7-8a48-6c357e1d6d61}" EventSourceName="COM" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">10031</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-11-29T12:34:18.1932644Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>27780</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="5708" ThreadID="1852" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>hw2.masiutin.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>{45FB4600-E6E8-4928-B25E-50476FF79425}</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

How can I fix this problem and/or prevent this error from appearing in the log?

Comment: This error goes all the way back to 2016 - that process will be MonitoringHost.exe - and MSFT *still* haven't fixed it. Apparently it's a false alert if SCOM or whatever is still functioning OK. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/325ab240-5eff-4a4b-9f5b-2eaf2a4002ed/an-unmarshaling-policy-check-was-performed-when-unmarshaling-a-custom-marshaled-object-and-the-class?forum=systemcenterservicemanager

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible fix for your error:

1.Start by identifying which process or service is triggering this error.

2.Check Task Manager for the *process ID* `5708` (in the above sample, but will probably be different when you go back to check).

3.Check which identity that process or service is running as.
*Task Manager will also show you this in the `User` column. If it is a service, you can check Service Manager to see which identity it is configured to run as*.

4.Once you have identified the user or service account that this process uses, make a note of it and head to *Registry Editor.*

5.Search the registry for the *class `GUID`*. For each instance found, change the permissions to grant the above service account and the SYSTEM identity `FULL` privilege to the key and its subkeys. (*I have seen suggestions to add Administrators here as well, but it's best to target this to the specific service account, if possible.*)

6.Once your process identity has permissions on the class key[s], reboot the system, and it should be resolved.

Similar posts, if you want to compare notes:

[1] - https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/108499-event-id-10031-a.html

[2] - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/325ab240-5eff-4a4b-9f5b-2eaf2a4002ed/an-unmarshaling-policy-check-was-performed-when-unmarshaling-a-custom-marshaled-object-and-the-class?forum=systemcenterservicemanager